# Drop-down note taker for Android

Tags: android, note-taking, widget

My Android has a drop-down menu that displays things like Wi-Fi Status, Bluetooth status, and S Finder.

**Question:** Is there an app that has the ability to add a note-taking widget to the drop down menu?  That way, whenever I'm in any sort of app, I'll be able to simply drop down the menu and jot a quick note.

Answer (score 1):

### [Todoist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.todoist)

Todoist is a to-do list manager multi-platform app. It has the option to set a permanent notification so you could add tasks and notes from any screen by simply swiping down:

[image] [image]

<sup>(Click pictures for higher res versions)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** At some point, you may need to utilize [QuickShortcutMaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut) or [Activity Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.szalkowski.activitylauncher&hl=en) app.

---

You're definitely going to need root access to show or remove anything from the Quick Settings drawer.

Gravitybox (*gratis*; requires [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)) can do it. It is available for Android [Jelly Bean](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.gm2.gravitybox), [Kitkat](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.kitkat.gravitybox), and [Lollipop](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.lollipop.gravitybox).

> GravityBox is a module [whose] primary goal is to provide the users of AOSP devices
>   with a tweak box to turn their vanilla AOSP ROM into custom ROM packed with additional features and tweaks
>   without need to flash anything. Most of the preferences can be changed on-the-fly without rebooting.

The ROM needs to be close to AOSP in order for this module to work (ideally).

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

### Instructions

1. Launch **Gravitybox → Statusbar Tweaks → QuickSettings management**
2. Go to **Statusbar QuickSettings tile** → select **Quick App → OK**
3. Go to **Tile specific settings → QuickApp tile settings → Main application**

   Now, there are many choices for you.

   1. If the note taking app directly launches into an editor then choose the app under **Applications**.
   2. If it has a shortcut which can launch its editor then select the app under **Shortcuts**.
   3. If none of those two options are available to launch the app's editor directly but a widget can do it, then use [Popup Widget 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.popupWidget) (paid) to create a  widget that can be launched from anywhere. See my answer for the question [How do I launch a widget from a shortcut on Home screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120930/96277)

      After that choose **Popup Widget 2** as shortcut under that **Shortcuts** options of **GravityBox**.
      Alternatively, [Overlays - Float Everywhere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.applay.overlay) can also help.

---

An an alternative of adding an icon into the Quick-Settings drawer, you can consider [Overlays - Float Everywhere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.applay.overlay). It can create a **global sidebar** where you can add your widgets. The sidebar remains hidden unless you show it by swiping from the left edge towards right direction. See more info on its [website](http://www.applay.co/).

<sub>(Click image to enlarge; source: official website)</sub>

[IMG:  http://www.applay.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Screenshot_2013-08-18-08-36-52.png](http://www.applay.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Screenshot_2013-08-18-08-36-52.png)

### Instructions

1. Enable the sidebar from **Home → Settings → Sidebar** → slide **Sidebar** → configure as per your needs
2. Thereafter, add a widget into the app. See my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/122988/96277) for basic *know-how*.
3. Close the app, go to home screen, drag the sidebar and add the entry.

[Here](http://www.applay.co/2013/08/18/sidebar-control-your-profiles-everywhere/) is the official guide, should you need any help.

Done!

---

If the device is not rooted, then your best option is to use an app which uses a persistent notification as  Quick Settings. I don't remember specifically any app, but Play Store is filled with such apps, launcher apps mostly.

---

One more alternative, try [LMT Launcher](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1330150). It is a freeware app and needs root access *for some features*. Use its **global PIE navigation** feature to access your note taking app or its editor.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

> LMT is a tool for Android (tested already on multiple devices but should run on nearly all) that launches a command when [performed] single touch or multitouch gestures on the screen ([in] any app/screen/etc.). You can connect basic and advanced commands to any gesture LMT supports. In addition to the gestures you can activate a system-wide PieControl for navigation...

See my answer for basic *know-how* for the question [Page up and page down in web pages and elsewhere](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56561/96277).

Comment: And then there is [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) which can achieve what [this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/25181/14045) is able to achieve, but for any app :)